# How I can get an Android phone to vibrate while shaking it?

Tags: android, performance, sensors, shake, vibration

I am just curious if my app would work out this way to make it vibrate when the phone is shook:

```
if(event.values[0] > 1.0) {
    vibrator.vibrate(500);
}
else {
    if(event.values[1] > 1.0)
    vibrator.vibrate(500);
}
```

What I am doing is `SensorEventListener` and I and combining 2 listeners.

Will this work out doing it this way? I am unable to test it as I don't own an Android phone, so I am asking (programming-wise) if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work that way. Just make sure to stop handling the sensor events for the 500 milliseconds the phone is vibrating.

```
boolean isVibrating = false;
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

if(!isVibrating){
    if(event.values[0] > 1.0) {
        vibrate(500);
    } else if(event.values[1] > 1.0){
        vibrate(500);
    }
}

void vibrate(long time){
    isVibrating = true;
    vibrator.vibrate(time);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                isVibrating = false;
            }
        },
        time)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. for the stop handling part: which method should i use? cancel()?

Comment: I don't think you need to stop listening for the sensor. Just toggle a flag and wrap the code in an `if`.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a sample code. I haven't tested it, so it may have syntax errors, but I hope you get the idea.